# t-SQL: Use a variable to filter result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, geolocation

Pardon my naivety.

I have a query that allows you to find the distance between two points on a sphere, in this case, the distance between zip codes.

```
SELECT  TOP 5 zip, city, state, latitude, longitude,
    69.0 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(latpoint))
            * COS(RADIANS(latitude))
            * COS(RADIANS(longpoint) - RADIANS(longitude))
            + SIN(RADIANS(latpoint))
            * SIN(RADIANS(latitude)))) AS distance_in_miles
FROM    us_loc_data
JOIN    (
         SELECT 39.317974 AS latpoint, -94.57545 AS longpoint 
        ) AS p ON 1=1
ORDER BY distance_in_miles
```

As you can see from the join, the result set is filtered by specifying a pair of coordinates as the "starting" point, and then returns a list of the top 5 nearest locations. (Example below)

[image]

Ultimately, I would like to filter the results by specifying a single starting *zip code* instead of a pair of coordinates. How can I implement a variable to do so? What is best practice?

Comment: please add some sample table data and the expected result - as well in formatted text. 
Also show us your current query attempt

Comment: Your current calculations are using a latitude and longitude to find the results. How would you use a zip code _instead_ of a pair of coordinates without changing the calculations? Using variables in SQL scripts is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but you can simply alter your sub-query to pull Lat/Lng by zip code.

```
Declare @Zip varchar(10) = '02806'

SELECT  TOP 5 zip, city, state, latitude, longitude,
    69.0 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(latpoint))
            * COS(RADIANS(latitude))
            * COS(RADIANS(longpoint) - RADIANS(longitude))
            + SIN(RADIANS(latpoint))
            * SIN(RADIANS(latitude)))) AS distance_in_miles
FROM    us_loc_data
JOIN    (
         SELECT latitude AS latpoint
              , longitude AS longpoint 
          From  us_loc_data 
          Where Zip = @Zip
        ) AS p ON 1=1
ORDER BY distance_in_miles
```

Comment: This is precisely what I wanted, I just wasn't sure how it would look. Thanks John!

Comment: @AnthonySims Happy it helped